# Civicase not appearing in Spark despite being enabled

Tags: civicase, civicrm-spark

I have purchased CiviCRM Spark and have walked through the set up list. I have activated civicase and it isn't appearing on the menu at all. I've logged in and out three times and waited at least two hours.

Thanks.

Comment: It might be a permission that's not set up by default - I'm not familiar with whether you can set your own permissions in spark but if you go to drupal's permissions (at People, then the Permissions tab) there are some there for civicase that might not be checked by default. You might also get better support for spark if you go to https://chat.civicrm.org and ask in the Spark channel.